# Alert value replace by string from dictionary by prometheus template

Tags: prometheus

I have SNMP monitoring of APC UPS in Prometheus.

I have such alert rule:

```
  - alert: 'APC status'
    expr: apc_snmp_power_status{job="apc_snmp"} != 2
    #snmp upsBasicOutputStatus, UID 1.3.6.1.4.1.318.1.1.1.4.1.1.0
    for: 3m
    labels:
      severity: 'warning'
    annotations:
      title: 'APC {{ $labels.apcname }} status error.'
      description: 'APC UPS management card  {{ $labels.instance }} reports that UPS {{ $labels.apcname }} is not in Online status. (status {{ $value }}). 
                      1: unknown \
                      2: onLine \
                      3: onBattery \
                      4: onSmartBoost \
                      5: timedSleeping \
                      6: softwareBypass \
                      7: off \
                      8: rebooting \
                      ... '
```

Is is possible to implement here any template, which will replace $value by the corresponging string from dictionary?

I want to receive notification in form

*'APC UPS management card  1.2.3.4 reports that UPS myAPC is in **onBattery** status. (status **3**).'*

Answer (score 2):

After several hours of digging, it seems to work:

```
  - alert: 'APC status'
    expr: apc_snmp_power_status{job="apc_snmp"} != 2
    #snmp upsBasicOutputStatus, UID 1.3.6.1.4.1.318.1.1.1.4.1.1.0
    for: 30s
    labels:
      severity: 'warning'
    annotations:
      title: 'APC {{ $labels.apcname }} status error.'
      description: 'APC UPS management card  {{ $labels.instance }} reports that UPS {{ $labels.apcname }} is in 
                    {{      if eq ($value | humanize) "1" }} unknown
                    {{ else if eq ($value | humanize) "2" }} onLine
                    {{ else if eq ($value | humanize) "3" }} onBattery
                    {{ else if eq ($value | humanize) "4" }} onSmartBoost
                    {{ else if eq ($value | humanize) "5" }} timedSleeping
                    {{ else if eq ($value | humanize) "6" }} softwareBypass
                    {{ else if eq ($value | humanize) "7" }} off
                    {{ else if eq ($value | humanize) "8" }} rebooting {{ end }} status. (status {{ $value }})'
```

The problem was to compare float64 type and int, I solved it by 'humanize' function and quotes around int.
I don't know GoLang, maybe there is another simpler solution.